# ARM multi-core penalty for Java programs

Tags: android, concurrency, arm, memory-barriers

I wonder if there is a penalty for running Dalvik+JIT on a multi-core ARM chip vs a single core chip?

E.g., if I disable multi-core support in my Android system build and execute the entire phone with a single CPU core, will I get higher performance when running a single-threaded Java benchmark?

How much is the cost of memory barrier and synchronization on multi-core?

I am asking because I vaugely remember seeing single-threaded benchmark scores from single core phones vs dual core phones. As long as the Mhz is about the same, there is no big difference between the two phones. I had expected a slow down in the dual-core phone ....

Comment: why would you expect a slow down in multicore systems?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "why don't you try it and find out?"

The complex answer is this:
There are costs to doing multicore synchronization but there are also benefits to have multiple cores.  You can undoubtedly devise a pathological case where a program suffers from the additional overhead of synchronization primitives such that it is deeply affected by their performance.  This is usually due to locking at too deep of a level (inside your fast loop).  But in the general case, the fact that the dozen other system programs are able to get CPU time on other cores, as well as the kernel servicing interrupts and IO on them instead of interrupting your process, are likely to greatly overwhelm the penalty incurred by MP synchronization.

In answer to your question, a DSB can take dozens or hundreds of cycles and a DMB is likely more costly.  Depending on the implementation exclusive load-store instructions can be very fast or very slow.  WFE can consume several microseconds, though it shouldn't be needed if you are not experiencing contention.

Comment: Thanks, but does anyone have any actual benchmark results? I am too lazy and resource deprived to do this meself.

Comment: And I was wondering if Dalvik has any sort of synchronization mechanism (similar to biased locking) that would favor single-threaded benchmarks (which sparingly use the "volatile" keyword) ...

Comment: I think you have the relative costs backwards -- `DMB` should be at least as fast as `DSB`, because `DSB` is synchronous.  Also, `DMB ST` will generally be faster than `DMB SY`.  I once did a simple benchmark on an Android SMP device that just executed `DMB` over and over, and got 13ns; meanwhile, the same thing on a UP device got 240ns.  So it's a good idea to always build for the right architecture.  Note the benchmark just measures the instantaneous instruction overhead, and may not reflect the overall systemic cost.

Answer (score 0):

Background: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html

Dalvik built for SMP does have additional overhead.  The Java Memory Model requires that certain guarantees be enforced, which means issuing additional memory barriers, particularly when dealing with volatile fields and immutable objects.

Whether or not the added overhead will be noticeable depends on what exactly you're doing and what device you're on, but generally speaking it's unlikely you'll notice it unless you're running a targeted benchmark.

If you build for UP and run Dalvik on a device with multiple cores, you may see flaky behavior -- see the "SMP failure example" appendix in the doc referenced above.